# Keeping temp tables in memory after switching servers?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I get #tempTable to stay in memory after switching servers.  Is this possible?

```
Select * 
into #tempTable
from dbo.table
```

I have data in server 1 that I want to compare in server 2, but I only have readonly access to server 2 (so I can't just move my data there), and the table in server 2 is too big to move to server 1.  This is why I want to know how to keep a temp table in memory after connecting to a new server.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Can't you just use a linked server without actually moving data between them?

Comment: I will look into that.  I am using SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: That's fine, but just so you know, you can't use temp tables from one server on another server

Comment: Very well, I apparently don't have permissions to add linked servers so I will have to write a C# script to tie these out.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Lamak This is stupid because if you have to do it you're probably doing something in a less than ideal way, but I found if you absolutely must query a temp table from a different server you can do it with a global temp table, linked server and `OPENQUERY`. I tested it and `Select * From [LinkedServer].[tempdb]..[##test]` failed, but `Select * From Openquery([LinkedServer],'Select * From ##test')` succeeded.

Comment: @Love2Learn yeah, but if op could have a linked server, then he wouldn't need the temp table and he could query that table directly. Anyway, he said the he couldn't create a linked server

Comment: @Lamak Yeah, I know what you mean and I completely agree, but I could see edge cases where it could make sense. I recently saw some question related to Linked Server query performance when pulling into an Oracle database from a SQL database. The linked server query wasn't honoring the proper indexes for some reason. If you ran the query natively on the SQL server to populate the global temp table you could then pull it over with a straight select from Oracle without worrying about indexes. Once again, probably a better way to do this outside of a linked server in this case.

Answer (score 1):

What you write is possible, but it just creates a temporary table on the server where the table is.

You probably want:

```
select *
into #Server2Table
from server2.database.dbo.table
```

You can then use `#Server2Table` in additional queries on the same connection where you copied it (such as the same window in SSMS or the same job step or the same stored procedure).  If you need it in a more permanent location, either use a global temporary table (starts with `##`) or a "real" table.

This requires the ability to link servers, using something like:

```
sp_addlinkedserver server2
```

You would run this on server1.  Perhaps your DBA will need to set it up.

I have found that queries often run faster when loading cross-server tables into a temporary table.  This is *not* because temporary tables are stored in memory.  This is because there is more information available about a table on a local server for the SQL optimizer to take advantage of.

Answer (score 0):

You could export the data from your query and import that into a database on your first server. You can use the SQL server import/export wizard. Bit convoluted, but if this happens a lot you can use SSIS to automate this move or even simply tick the 'Save this package' box. Once you have the data in your first server you can do whatever you like with it.

Comment: The size of the table makes this impossible unfortunately.

Comment: @sooprise What is it you are trying to do with your comparison?